# Is there a numpy api for transforming & flat-mapping rows of 2d array?

Tags: scipy, numpy-ndarray, flatmap

Suppose I have a 2d numpy array of positive integers:

```
[[1, 3]
 [2, 7]]
```

and to each element I would like to apply a function which transforms it into a sequence of integers, giving me:

```
[[[0,0,1],[0,1,1]]
 [[0,1,0],[1,1,1]]]
```

that I would like to have then flattened row-wise to:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I know this can be done step-by-step, but maybe there's a better, efficient both memory- and cpu-time wise Numpy/SciPy api for transformations like described above?
Thanks!

Comment: You start with a (2,2) array, create a (2,2,3) from that.  Reshaping that to (2,6) easy.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, although it still escapes me how to elegantly do that first step in python3. I tried wrapping my transforming function with  numpy's `vectorize` but then numpy complains that I am trying to set array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I've come with this, but it is far from elegant and concise in my book:

```
def fn(x):
    return np.array([int(c) for c in '{0:08b}'.format(x)])
F = np.frompyfunc(fn, 1, 1)

a = np.arange(6).reshape((2, 3))

np.vstack(np.hstack(F(a))).reshape((2, 24))
```

It is really difficult to comprehend there's no easier way than `frompyfunc` and combined `hstack` & `vstack`

Comment: If you flatten the array first you can get by with just one stack.

Comment: Good point! Still, I don't feel comfortable with creation of intermediate python objects.

Comment: Maybe if the new dimension could be added with empty values, like `np.empty` does, and then somehow the tranformation applied. Ultimately, I would like to have a solution which also works with sparse matrices.

Comment: So we could start with adding new axis, and then stacking the array with an empty one `[p, q, r - 1]`, and then applying function which will transform `[x, empty, .., empty]` into `[y_1, y_2, ..., y_r]`

Comment: Try `np.stack(np.frompyfunc(fn,1,1)(arr).ravel()).reshape(2,-1)`

Comment: I've used `def foo(x): return np.array(list(np.binary_repr(x,3)),int)`.  It still needs `frompyfunc` because `np.binary_repr` works with just one number at a time.  I have worked with binary rep enough to know how to do the conversion for an array of values  `binary_repr` seems to be taking care of a bunch of edge conditions that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I'll be checking implementation of `numpy.unpackbits` for inspiration as well.